# The logcat shows error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add a course to the course table from the adminpage activity but when i click the add course button the application force closes with the following error

Here's the logcat file:

```
02-19 00:57:55.826: E/global(354): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
02-19 00:57:55.826: E/global(354): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
02-19 00:57:55.826: E/global(354):  at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
02-19 00:57:55.826: E/global(354):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
02-19 00:57:55.826: E/global(354):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
02-19 00:57:55.826: E/global(354):  at com.example.universityattendance.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:38)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.example.universityattendance.AdminPage.addCrs(AdminPage.java:33)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  ... 11 more
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 00:58:45.665: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  ... 15 more
```

**ADMINPage.class**

```
public class AdminPage extends Activity{
    EditText txtCoursename,txtTeacherID,txtSem;
    DBAdapter dbAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adminpage);

        txtCoursename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCoursename);
        txtTeacherID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTPassword);
        txtSem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSem);

        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.open();

    }
    public void addCrs(View v){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtCoursename.getWindowToken(), 0);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtTeacherID.getWindowToken(), 0);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtSem.getWindowToken(), 0);
        try {

            String coursename = txtCoursename.getText().toString();
            String teacherID = txtTeacherID.getText().toString();
            String semester = txtSem.getText().toString();

            long i = dbAdapter.addCourse(coursename, Integer.parseInt(teacherID), Integer.parseInt(semester));
            if (i != -1)
                Toast.makeText(AdminPage.this,
                        "You have successfully added Course", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            dbAdapter.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(AdminPage.this, "Some problem occurred",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

here's the **adminpage.xml** file

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editCoursename"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editSem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/adCourseBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addCrs"
        android:text="Add Course" />
```

inside **DbAdapter.class**

```
public long addCourse(String coursename, int parseInt, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_COURSE_NAME, coursename);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TEACHER_ID, parseInt);
    initialValues.put("sem", i);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE3, null, initialValues);

}
```

Tables **Dbhelper.class**

```
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "attendance.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TAG = "STUDB";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 =
" CREATE TABLE teacher_data ( t_id integer primary key autoincrement, t_name text not null, t_pass text not null);";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 =
" CREATE TABLE student_data ( stud_id integer primary key autoincrement, stud_name text not null, stud_roll text not null, sem integer not null);";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE3 =
" CREATE TABLE course_data ( course_id integer primary key autoincrement, course_name text not null, t_id integer , sem integer );";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtTeacherID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTPassword);
```

There's no `editTPassword` view in the layout and a null is returned here. Invoking `getText()` in your `onClick` method here

```
String teacherID = txtTeacherID.getText().toString();
```

causes the NPE.

Generally, NullPointerExceptions are quite easy to debug. Look at the exception stacktrace to see the line of code where the exception occurs and figure out what could be `null` there. Change it and test again. You can also place debugger breakpoints to inspect the variables of a running program.

Comment: Thank you @laalto how did i miss this :D... you a life saver